# Bootstrap 3 navbar on mobile - desired hover effect not seen

Tags: html, css, navbar

I'm attempting to make a website for a store, and I'm using a Bootstrap navbar. 
This is how I want the navbar to function: when the user clicks "about", a dropdown menu becomes visible, and then the user can click one of the submenu categories. After hovering, focusing, or clicking on, let's say, the "store hours" subcategory, I want "store hours" to change background color, and then for the entire menu to collapse/close. 
On my Mac everything works perfectly, but on mobile one thing happens differently: upon clicking "store hours", the menu collapses immediately without the user seeing the background color of "store hours" change first. When I resize my window on my computer it functions the way it should, but on mobile something else I'm not sure of is going on...

Here is the website with just the navbar displayed for the sake of simplicity: http://nikmash.com. If you see it on a mobile device, you'll hopefully see what I'm trying to explain.

If anyone miraculously knows what's going on here and has advice, I would really appreciate it!

Here is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Discount Luggage of Hollywood</title>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arvo:700,400" rel="stylesheet">
      <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/js/all.js"></script> 
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script> <!-- we need jquery because JS uses it -->
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">


        $(document).click(function (event) {
        var clickover = $(event.target);
        var $navbar = $(".navbar-collapse");               
        var _opened = $navbar.hasClass("in");
        if (_opened === true && !clickover.hasClass("navbar-toggle")) {      
            $navbar.collapse('hide');
        }
        });

      </script> 
   </head>
   <body>
          <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
         <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
               <button type="button" class="pull-left navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-nav-demo" aria-expanded="false">
                  <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
               </button>
               <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Business</a>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-nav-demo">
               <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                  <li class="dropdown">
                     <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fas fa-suitcase"></i> About <span class="caret"></span></a>
                     <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li class = "diff"><a href="#"> <i class="far fa-clock"></i> Store Hours</a></li>
                        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                        <li class = "diff"><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i> Location & Directions</a></li>
                        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                        <li class = "diff"><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-car"></i> Parking</a></li>            
                     </ul>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i> Reviews</a></li>
               </ul>
            </div>
         </div>
      </nav>

   </body>
</html>
```

And CSS:

```
body{
padding-top: 70px;
text-align: center;
height: 100%;
}

html{
height:100%;
}

.navbar-brand{
position: absolute;
transform: translateX(-50%);
left: 50%;
text-align: center;
}

.navbar-toggle {
z-index:3;
background-color: white;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
background-color: black;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus, .navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover{
background-color:#9da6b5;
}

.navbar{
background-color: rgba(1, 1, 1, .9);
border:none;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a{
transition: background-color .3s;
color: #9da6b5;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:focus, .navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:hover{
background-color: white;
}

.navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu{
background-color: rgba(1, 1, 1, .9);
}

.navbar-default .navbar-brand:focus, .navbar-default .navbar-brand:hover {
color:#9da6b5;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-brand{
transition: color .5s;
color: white;
}

.dropdown-menu>li>a{
transition: background-color .3s;
color:#9da6b5;
}
.dropdown-menu>li>a:focus, .dropdown-menu>li>a:hover{
background-color: white;

}

@media (max-width: 767px){

.navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu{
  background-color: rgba(60, 63, 68,.5)
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu>li>a{
color: #9da6b5;
text-align: center;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu>li>a:focus, .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu>li>a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu>li>a:active{
background-color: white;
}

}

@media(max-width: 576px){
.navbar-brand{
transform: translateX(0);
left:0;
right: 0;
text-align: right;
left:10%;
}
}

@media (max-width: 321px){
.navbar-brand{
font-size: 15px;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

***:hover behavior doesn’t exist on touch screen devices.* On iOS :hover is triggered before the click event, so you will see the hover style for a brief moment before the page changes.**

For more [**info**](https://www.prowebdesign.ro/how-to-deal-with-hover-on-touch-screen-devices/)